# How to create a formula that depends on the value of another formula - R

Tags: r, formula, differential-equations

[image]

```vba
H2 = 0

H3 - H999 = =SQRT(EXP(G3*0,1))*NORMINV(RAND();0;1)

I2 - I999 = =$E$2+$D$2*EXP($A$2*($G2-$B$2)+$C$2)/(1+EXP($A$2*($G2-$B$2)+$C$2))+H2
```

Hi guys,

i created the formula obove in excel.
I want to implement this one to R. Can anyone help me with this?

I already tried to do it with formula and with data.frame.

The probelm is that sigma depends on t and X(t)-1.

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks,
Max

Edit for further question:
[Simulation with sigma only depending on t in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBblb.png)

[Simulation with sigma only depending on t in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFi6p.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow
Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and xkcd.com/2116). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., data.frame(...) or the output from dput(head(x))) directly.

Comment: please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you want to simulate a stochastic dynamical system, you should try to use the tools that were developed for that purpose. It might also help the presentation of the task if you were to write the SDE as formula instead of the spreadsheet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to require a `for` loop. If the intention is the run this multiple times to get `X(t)`, then the replications can be vectorized within the `for` loop:

```
fXt <- function(A, B, C, D, E, delta, steps, n) {
  t <- seq(delta, by = delta, length.out = steps)
  # pre-allocate Xt and sigma
  Xt <- matrix(rep(E + D*exp(A*(t - B) + C)/(1 + exp(A*(t - B) + C)), each = n), n, steps)
  sigma <- matrix(0, n, steps)
  r <- matrix(exp(0.025)*rnorm(n*(steps - 1L)), n, steps - 1L) # sqrt(exp(0.05)) = exp(0.025)
  
  for (i in 2:steps) {
    sigma[,i] <- r[,i - 1L]*sqrt(abs(Xt[,i - 1L] - 50))
    Xt[,i] <- Xt[,i] + sigma[,i]
  }
  
  t(Xt)
}
```

Call it like so:

```
Xt <- fXt(2, 5, 3, 30, 100, 0.05, 998, 100)
```

`Xt` will be a matrix with 998 rows and 100 columns. Each column is a different replication.